# Change custom taxonomy after certain time – CPT template

Tags: custom-post-types

I wish to change the custom taxonomy for the custom post type after a certain time similar to post expiration.
Custom taxonomy: current-status
term-id: 368
post-type: job

I have created the function `wp_set_post_categories` and wish to include it in the post-job template in the generatepress child theme after `generate_do_template_part( 'page' );`.
Does this create any issues?

```php
$nvs_taxonomy = 'custom-status';
//expiration time
$expirationtime = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'expiration', false);
if( count( $expirationtime ) != '' ) {
    if (is_array($expirationtime)) {
        $expirestring = implode($expirationtime);
    }

    $secondsbetween = strtotime($expirestring)-time();

    if ( $secondsbetween >= 0 ) {
        echo 'This post will expire on ' .$expirestring.'';
        the_content();
    } else {
        function set_new_category( $post_id ) {
            //Define new category by ID
            $new_category = array( 368 );
            $old_term = wp_get_post_terms( $post_id, $nvs_taxonomy );

            if( is_array( $old_term ) && ! empty( $old_term ) ) {
                if ( in_array( 'custom-status', $old_term ) {
                    wp_set_post_categories( $post_id, $new_category, $append = true );
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Following the advice of Mr. @Buttered_Toast I have modified the code little bit to use timestamp data directly. However, in that, I have noticed a "**PHP Warning: A non-numeric value encountered in /single-job.php on line 34**"

```
if ( generate_has_default_loop() ) {
   while ( have_posts() ) :
   the_post();
    $expire_timestamp = rwmb_meta( 'j_post_expire' );// line 31      
    $current_time = time(); // line 32
    
    // Ensure the timestamp parsed correctly.
    if ( $expire_timestamp ) {
    $seconds_between = $expire_timestamp - $current_time; //line 34
    if ( $seconds_between >= 0 ) {
       generate_do_template_part( 'single' );
    } else {
    wp_set_post_terms( $post->ID, array ( 368 ), 'current-status', true );
    wp_remove_object_terms( $post->ID, array ( 367 ), 'current-status' );
     generate_do_template_part( 'single' );
     }
    } else {
    generate_do_template_part( 'single' );
    }
    endwhile;
    }
```

To overcome the non-numeric error, I have initialized the variable ($seconds_between) as an integer.

```
$seconds_between = 0; //intialize as integer after line 32
```

In other way, we can define other variables ($current_time and $expire_timestamp) with (int)

```
$seconds_between = (int)$expire_timestamp - (int)$current_time;//declaring variables as integer
```

- If there is any better way, please share to correct it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got a number of issues with you code...

1. `if (is_array($expirationtime))` is redundant because [`get_post_meta`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_meta/) will always return an array if the third parameter is false.
2. `implode($expirationtime);` requires a separator, e.g. `implode(' ', $expirationtime);`.
3. `strtotime` can fail to parse your input resulting in a false value. You will get an error when trying to perform `false - time()`.
4. You're defining a function with `function set_new_category() {}` but not using it.
5. [`wp_set_post_categories`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_set_post_categories/) is for setting terms for the category taxonomy. For custom taxonomies, use [`wp_set_post_terms`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_set_post_terms/) instead.

With all of the above fixed, you should end up with something like...

```php
$expiration_time = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'expiration', false );

if ( count( $expiration_time ) ) {

    $expire_string = implode( ' ', $expiration_time );
    $expire_timestamp = strtotime( $expire_string );

    // Ensure the timestamp parsed correctly.
    if ( $expire_timestamp ) {
        $seconds_between = $expire_timestamp - time();

        if ( $secondsbetween >= 0 ) {
            echo 'This post will expire on ' . $expire_string;
            the_content();
        } else {
            wp_set_post_terms( $post->ID, [ 368 ], 'custom-status', true );
        }
    }

}
```

This isn't a complete answer but should definitely point you in the right direction.

Comment: Technically, testing the type of `$expirationtime` is best practice, as `get_post_meta` may return false or an empty string in certain circumstances.

Comment: Thank you sir for your code.

Comment: Based on your code, I have modified it a bit for "timestamp" data instead of normal m/d/y H:I:s.

Thank you so much for your valuable time and knowledge.

Comment: I have noticed a "PHP Warning: A non-numeric value encountered in /single-job.php on line 34" - while using time() function.